# Coleman Wall furnace in 1967 mobile home gas model # 8670A

Tags: hvac

My old wall gas furnace blower motor keeps running and shutting off not cooling the system down and smells hot inside and outside?

Comment: What is your question? I would agree if it smells hot and shuts down that sounds safe, what do you want to ask?

Comment: Shuts down before cooling completely? Or runs and runs and runs, never shutting off, but still smells hot? Could be a hi-limit switch that is faulty.